# Shopify color filter with or condition

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

is there any way to adjust a template search query?
I want to color filter with/Or Condition.
For example:

- if I select a Black color: all products with black color should appear.
- if I added White color: all white products and black products and products with black and white color should appear.
  The current behavior of all Shopify themes when you select the black and white colors they only show the product that has both colors on them.
  an example of what I'm sarching exactly :
  https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/227/limited-editions?p=2031&p=813&p=1165&orderBy=Published

Comment: Are you  referring to filtering items on collection pages or changing Shopify's search-page behaviour?  Either way Shopify's native options are somewhat limited, but on a search page you might be able to get creative with search queries. To get more detailed filtering and customization on collection pages, I would recommend checking out some of the various apps available on the app store that do this.

Comment: I don't mind the way as long as I can achieve the result,
can you suggest to me any app free or paid that can help me achieve that?
otherwise, do you have any idea how to change Shopify's search page behaviour?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shopify's native options are somewhat limited, but on a search page you might be able to get creative with search queries. You can find details on the advanced search query parameters that Shopify supports in their help document: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/use-advanced-query-parameters-in-shopify-online-store-search

Otherwise, to get more detailed filtering and customization on collection and search pages, I would recommend checking out some of the various apps that are available on the app store. I have worked on projects to make one-off custom filter & sort features for stores before using only what's available through the front-end, and I can say with some confidence that attempting to make a custom feature using nothing but the front-end APIs and information will take a lot more work and will probably run much slower than using a dedicated app that can handle a lot of the data and optimizations server-side.

I do not have experience with a wide variety of filter/sort/search plugins, but one that I have worked with a few times is "Product Filter and Search" by BoostCommerce. This app works well out-of-the-box and has the potential for extensive customization, though as expected the more you want to customize it the more time and effort you'll need to put in during the setup.

Many apps on the app store offer a free trial period, so you could try out multiple apps to decide which one you like the best.  If you do any shopping around, I would recommend that you make sure to make a duplicate, unpublished theme for each app and only ever install one app per theme.  (Having multiple apps installed that all try to affect the same part of the page often leads to very messy situations.)  Here is a link to Shopify's app store searching for "Collection Filter" to get a list of available apps: https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=collection+filter